# Unnecessary second query for an EXISTS in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a simple EXISTS query using ActiveRecord. It seems to be running 2 queries for some reason.

```
User.where("exists (select 'X' from roles where roles.role = 'teacher' and roles.user_id = users.id)")
```

From the log

Query 1

```
     (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "users" WHERE (users.id <> 3 and exists (select 'X' from roles where roles.role = 'teacher' and roles.user_id = users.id)) LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

Query 2

```
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.id <> 3 and exists (select 'X' from roles where roles.role = 'teacher' and roles.user_id = users.id)) LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

Is there a way to avoid this. I would write the query directly in SQL a bit like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u,
     roles r
WHERE r.user_id = u.id
 AND u.id <> #{@user.id}
 AND r.role = 'teacher'
```

Comment: is 'roles' a separate table?

Comment: Yes it is ... a separate table

Comment: have you tried eager loading or joining the roles table? Something like `User.includes(:roles).where("query")` or `User.joins(:roles).where("query")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ... still 2 queries. Seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: fair enough. There's also the `where_exists` gem https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists

Comment: Cool gem ... but it seems to wrap ActiveRecord so probably generates the 2 queries also. https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists/blob/master/lib/where_exists.rb

Comment: Exists does check for a record whether it exists or not by querying a count query to db (Query 1). What exactly you trying to achieve there? If you only want to know whether such records exists or not, use the where clause and check `.present?` at the end. And if want to select `'X'` too then you can use `.pluck(:x)` or `.select(:x)` in the end. If it results in empty array, no records exists.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Thanks for your post. The second query I posted fully completes the query at a SQL level. With ActiveRecord, Rails is first running the count query. So there is an unnecessary query being run, which if possible, I'd like to avoid. I could also run direct SQL and use find_by_sql but returns an Array and not an ActiveRecord object.